# Showing $\frac{\sin(x+a)-\sin(x)}{a}= \frac{\cos(x+\frac{a}{2})\sin\frac{a}{2}}{a/2}$

Tags: trigonometry

In my mathematics textbook, when deriving the differential of sin(x), it goes from the first expression to the second one without any explanation as to why.

$$\frac{\sin(x+a)-\sin(x)}{a}= \frac{\cos(x+\frac{a}{2})\sin\frac{a}{2}}{a/2}$$

Myself and my flatmates have been attempting to rearrange it for about an hour now with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the [sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite

$$ \sin(x+a)-\sin(a) $$

as

$$\sin\left(\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)+\frac{a}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)-\frac{a}{2}\right)$$

then apply the sum and difference formulas for $\sin$ and simplify.

Comment: Wow, would have never thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: There are useful identities associated with $\sin(A+B)\pm\sin(A-B)$ also the same with $\cos$. You should investigate them when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

They simply use one of the four *factorisation formulæ*, namely
$$\sin p-\sin q=2\sin\Bigl (\frac{p-q}2\Bigr)\cos\Bigl (\frac{p+q}2\Bigr),$$
which is a consequence of this corollary of the *addition formulæ*:
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)-\sin(\alpha-\beta)=2\cos\alpha\sin\beta.$$